# Gatsby build on Netlify failing with the objects must have internal.contentDigest

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a Gatsby/Wordpress site running on Netlify and the build will fail unless I manually run the build and clear cache option. This is the error I'm receiving

```
error the objects must have internal.contentDigest. Current object:
{
  "objectID": "cG9zdGozNDc=",
  "uri": "/post-name/",
  "title": "Post Name",
  "excerpt": "This is a post..."
}
```

I'm not sure what to try, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably an error coming from `gatsby-plugin-algolia`.
https://github.com/algolia/gatsby-plugin-algolia#partial-updates

> We rely on Gatsby's default contentDigest field, so make sure it is queried.

Adding `internal.contentDigest` to the query passed to the plugin would solve the issue.

Comment: Just Adding internal.contentDigest did not help in my case as we used transformer method to convert the graphql object to desired object that will be pushed to algolia. So we have to added the internal.contentDigest to the transformed object as well to fix the issue.  Hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by cleaning the gatsby cache.

`npx gatsby clean`